# Why is this resulting in infinite loop

Tags: assembly, fasm

```
format ELF64 executable

segment readable executable

SYSCALL_EXIT = 60
SYSCALL_WRITE = 1
STD_IN = 0
STD_OUT = 1

macro exit code {
    mov rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
    mov rdi, code
    syscall
}

macro write fd, buf, size {
    mov rax, SYSCALL_WRITE
    mov rdi, fd
    mov rsi, buf
    mov rdx, size
    syscall
}

entry main
main:
    mov rcx, 5; All loop instructions automatically decrement this register
my_loop:
    write STD_OUT, msg, msg_len
    loop my_loop
    exit 0

msg db "Hello", 10
msg_len = $ - msg
```

The above code goes into an infinite loop. my guess is that system call write is somehow modifying the rcx register, which is decremented by loop and expected to be 0 for the loop to stop. But I am not seeing anywhere documented this behavior of write. Why is rcx used as default loop counter if other things can modify this register.

Tried running this code, was expecting it to run 5 times. Instead it keeps printing Hello infinitely many times.

Comment: *Why is rcx used as default loop counter if other things can modify this register.* - x86-64 has evolved a *lot* since 8086, where the architect (Steve Mores) explained [in his book](https://stevemorse.org/8086/) that the `loop` instruction ([which is slow on most modern CPUs and shouldn't be used except for code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)) was intended as a complement for `rep movsb` and similar, when you wanted to do something to each character.  Not necessarily for loops in general.

Comment: The architects of AMD64 didn't put any value in RCX as a loop counter; you can loop with any register more efficiently.  Also, ECX was call-clobbered in the standard 32-bit calling conventions anyway (because it's often needed for variable-count shifts), and only hand-written asm would be using raw `syscall` instead of making calls to opaque library functions (`call write` in compiler-generated code) that have to be assumed to clobber all call-clobbered registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks that is very useful. I will stop using loop for looping and instead use jnz for now.